# Home Page and Admin Page react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently developing a React application that consists of two main sections: a customer-facing home page and an admin panel.

The home page serves as an interface for customers to send messages via a form.

Meanwhile, the admin panel is a separate section designed for administrators to view incoming customer messages and respond to them.

My question is when I run `npm run start-client` instead of displaying the ClientApp it displays the App.js which is only for the admin!

Here is my code:

ClientApp.js

```
function ClientApp() {
  return (
    <div >
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar/> 
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element = {<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='/about' element = {<About banner = {about_banner} category="about"/>}/>       
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
      </BrowserRouter>  
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClientApp;
```

Clientindex.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import ShopContextProvider from './Context/ShopContext';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <ShopContextProvider>
    <App />
  </ShopContextProvider>
    
  
);
```

.js

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider,  Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import AdminHome from "./pages/AdminHome/AdminHome"
import Login from "./pages/Login/Login";
import AdminNav from "./components/adminnavbar/AdminNav"
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/authcontext";




function App() {
  const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  

  const Layout = () => {
    return (
     <div>
        <AdminNav />
        
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      return <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }

    return children;
  };

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: (
        <ProtectedRoute>
          <Layout />
        </ProtectedRoute>
      ),
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <AdminHome />,
        },
       
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      element: <Login />,
    },
    
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
  import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./context/authcontext";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <App />
      </AuthContextProvider>
    
  </React.StrictMode>
);
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "dom": "^0.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.19.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "router": "^1.3.8",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start-client": "react-scripts start --env=client",
    "start-admin": "react-scripts start --env=admin"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify what the exact specific issue or problem is that you need help with here. What does "separated from each other" mean?

Comment: The client is currently unable to access the admin panel. I've developed a login page and an admin panel, both rendered via the app.js file. Now, I'm considering creating a customerApp.js file along with its corresponding index.js file. Alternatively, I'm exploring methods to directly render a homepage that caters to customers, allowing them to land on it seamlessly. Could you provide guidance on the best approach?"

Comment: *What* admin panel are you referring to? Are you having trouble accessing a specific route you are rendering in `App`? Do you need to provide a more complete [mcve] that includes all the relevant code you are working with? We can't really help if we can't see all the code you have and don't understand what you want it to do.

Comment: hello ! so i've create app.js file where i render the admin page.............and now i created clientapp.js to render the client page  im gona copy the clientapp.js and clientindex.js and also the package.json file :

Comment: So you are trying to render two different React apps?  What are the `--env=client` or `--env=admin` flags supposed to do? Can you share the complete package.json file? I suspect your app has only the one entry point that renders the `App` component.

Comment: --env=client to start the clientapp.js ....--env=admin for the adminapp.js but im using theapp.js file for the admin side so theres no use for --env=admin ...........................and i updated my post so you can see the package.json file....thank you and i hope you can provide me with some help :

Comment: Yeah, my question was more about this `--env` script parameter. I don't see anything in what you've shared that would make the `"start-client"` script do anything different than the `"start-admin"` script. From what I can tell, they do the same thing, start the app and run/render the `App` component.

Answer (score 0):

**You can consider having different entry points for each section and run your application using specified scripts:-**

*index.js file for customer section:-*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './CustomerApp';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />)
```

*index.js file for admin section:-*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AdminApp from './AdminApp';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<AdminApp />);
```

*Route component for CustomerApp.js:-*

```
<div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About banner={about_banner} category="about" />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

*Route component for AdminApp.js:-*

```
<div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Admin />} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

*Update your package.json file:-*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start-customer": "react-scripts start --env=customer",
    "start-admin": "react-scripts start --env=admin"
  }
}
```